# Javascript window.close() workarounds don't work on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window, window.closed

**Before anyone marks this question as duplicate,** I would like to say that all the other answers are from 2014 or older. The workarounds or hacks do NOT work anymore on the updated versions of Chrome.

I have a logout page that needs to be closed upon clicking a link. I have read about how Javascript cannot close the window if the same script hasn't opened the window.

I am currently using Javascript to achieve this. How can this be done? (Basically, shut the tab using Javascript).

I have tried the latest answers such as:

```
var win = window.open("window.opener.location", "_self");
win.close();
```

**which don't work anymore!** Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to close the logout page's window after the user logged out?  Wouldn't a page with a "You've successfully logged out" message be more appropriate?

Comment: The workarounds or hacks don't work because you're not supposed to be able to do it. They were bugs, and the browser vendors fixed them. Why do you think there should still be a way to do it?

Comment: If there were a well known way to do it, the vendors will probably fix it soon, so you'll constantly be looking for new ways around it. Just give up now.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmations @AdamKonieska and thank you!

Comment: Thanks to @Barmar as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only close windows/tabs that you create yourself. That is, you cannot programmatically close a window/tab that the user creates.

For example, if you create a window with window.open() you can close it with window.close().